# How to Call function as a variable in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**Example :**

Creating function

```
const isElementLoaded = () => {
     //Logic
              return true;
    }
```

**Calling function using this.isElementLoaded :**

```
  if (this.isElementLoaded)
   {
        //output true
  }
```

Comment: `this.isElementLoaded()` ? (as any function in typescript or javascript, by the way)

Comment: i don't want to use round brackets

Comment: You can use a getter instead, which is used like a property. `get isElementLoaded(): boolean { return true; }`

Comment: Why don’t you want to use parentheses?

Comment: @evolutionxbox may be his (,)  keys are damaged/not functioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `()`, you need to make it an accessor property. (The only other way to call it without `()` is to use it as a tag function on a tagged template literal, which doesn't seem relevant to what you're doing. :-) )

In a `class`, you'd do that like this:

```
class Example {
    get isElementLoaded() {
        return /*...appropriate value...*/;
    }
}
```

In an object literal, it's basically the same:

```
const obj = {
    get isElementLoaded() {
        return /*...appropriate value...*/;
    }
};
```

In either case, TypeScript should be able to infer the return type from your `return` statement, but if necessary add the annotation, e.g.:

```
class Example {
    get isElementLoaded(): boolean {
        return /*...appropriate value...*/;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to add an accessor to an object after it's created, you use `defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "isElementLoaded", {
    get() {
        return /*...appropriate value...*/;
    },
    // flags here if appropriate; they default to `false` if omitted
});
```

You'll need to be sure the type information for the object includes the accessor (perhaps as an optional property).

Answer (score 1):

Either you use a *function* and then you *need* to use `()` to call the function (that's the TypeScript / JavaScript syntax):

```
const isElementLoaded = () => {
     //Logic
              return true;
    }


  // in a function:

  if (this.isElementLoaded()) {
        //output true
  }
```

Or, you can use a property on your `class` with a getter:

```
 get isElementLoaded() {
     //Logic
              return true;
    }

 // in a function

  if (this.isElementLoaded) {
        //output true
  }
```

Comment: Thanks i got my answer !!!

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: use this.isElementLoaded()

You are actually not calling the function you created there. You are using arrow notation to create a function, you could do the same with

```
function isElementLoaded(...){...}
```

which would it make more clear maybe that you have to call it to actually do something. By just calling the name of the function you reference to the function body - but that is not progressed in any way.
Here's a quick try-out example: https://jsbin.com/kekifugoqe/edit?js,console
Hit 'run' and you see the difference in the output.